# Getting subview location after superview rotation

Tags: ios, uiview, rotation, transform

I have a UIView which has several subviews that respond to touch. If I rotate the **layer** of the superview with some code like this:

```
[CATransaction begin];
[CATransaction setDisableActions:true];
view.layer.transform = CATransform3DRotate(view.layer.transform, angle, 0, 0, 1);
[CATransaction commit];
```

... then I can't seem to find the right location of the subviews when responding to touch events... Any ideas?

Comment: Use NSLog(@"%@", subview.view); to locate the problem

Comment: Seems like the subviews think they are still in the same place. I'll keep trying...

Comment: Could it be that the layer's transform property be different from it's UIView's?

Comment: Part of the problem seems to be that I am using a bezier for hit detection in my subviews. Could it be that the bezier needs to be updated for the transformation... I tried some code in that way since `UIBezierPath` has an `applyTransform` method, but it is not helping the way I am doing it right now...

Answer (score 3):

I found it, worked out beautifully I guess. I needed to convert points between UIViews for doing bezier hit testing:

```
-(BOOL)containsPoint:(CGPoint)point
{
    point = [self.superview.superview convertPoint:point toView:self];
    return [self.slicePath containsPoint:point];
}
```